# How to pass exactly selected listview row text in android?

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView which manipulates 10 row. Each row has two TextView. If I select a row, I want to know the current TextView text. I know that getView() method call multiple times. For this reason I did not get the exact text. Suppose that if I select first row then I get the last row text. How to get rid of this problem. Any suggestion will be appreciated. Here the getView() method:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    rowItem = getItem(position);
    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_layout, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        /*
         * holder.rlListViewImg = (RelativeLayout) convertView
         * .findViewById(R.id.rl_listview_img);
         */

        holder.ivMain = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.image_view_main);
        holder.tvModule = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_module);
        holder.tvClasses = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_classes);
        holder.tvHours = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_hours);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    holder.tvModule.setText(rowItem.getModule());
    // mCurrentModule = rowItem.getModule();
    holder.tvClasses.setText(rowItem.getClasses());
    holder.tvHours.setText(rowItem.getHours());

    convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d("MY TEXT", "" + rowItem.getModule());
            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), ModuleActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("MODULE", rowItem.getModule());
            getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: can you post your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

implement the OnItemClickListener function:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position,
                long arg3) {

            ((TextView)view). // do what you need here
        }
    });
```

Notice that you get the position also, so you can implement whatever you need for the array also.

Edit: please avoid using onItemClickListener & implement onClick to your convertView
you can do better with the listView.setOnItemClickListener function.

Comment: Actually your answer did not help me. Because in main class I extends Activity and my listview id is id="@+id/mylistview".

Comment: it's the same. so change the variable from listView to your list view variable you got from findViewById(...)

Comment: so its a different issue. if its null pointer so how you can see your listview with the adapter? are you getting null pointer exception in findViewById(R.id.mylistview); ?

Comment: Ok your solution is now works fine. Actually I did some non sense issu. But I have another question .......How I get the TextView Id which is currently selected in listview.

Comment: You used ((TextView)view) but how can I know which textview it is actually.

Comment: that's why you get position parameter and you can implement any logic with it.

Comment: at last I got solution. Thanks for your excellent helps. Credit is goes to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the setOnItemClickListener method of Listview

Ex:

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
{
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) 
    {
          String text = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();
    }
```

}